# Spring boot is not able to read docker-compose environmental variables

Tags: spring-boot, docker-compose, environment-variables, application.properties

I am having a "boring" problem here. Let me explain...

I am trying read some 'environmental variables' from my docker-compose, in my Application.properties.

Although, I am creating properly the env's variables in the containers(I can see that when I inspect the containers), they are not being read from the spring boot Applications.

Its kinda, these 'docker-compose environmental variables', seems like "are not accessible".

I am doing a TEST (); so, I am trying to get an environmental variable in my Spring Application, and it's resulting in 'null', such as:

```
@Slf4j
@SpringBootApplication(exclude = R2dbcAutoConfiguration.class)
public class AppDriver {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        
        System.out.println(  "container variables >>>>> " + System.getenv("MASTER_URL")   );

        SpringApplication.run(AppDriver.class,args);
    }
```

The log is:

> conteiner variables >>>>> null

Below, They are my docker-compose (i do not have any Spring boot service in the docker-compose[for now]):

```
version: "3.5"

services:

  tenant1:
    image: postgres
    ports:
      - "5432:5432"
    restart: always
    environment:
      POSTGRES_PASSWORD: password
      POSTGRES_DB: tenant1
      POSTGRES_USER: user
    volumes:
      - ./data/tenant1:/var/lib/postgresql

  mysql:
    image: mysql:5.7
    ports:
      - "3306:3306"
    environment:
      MASTER_URL: r2dbc:mysql://user:password@localhost/master
      MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD: mysecret
      MYSQL_USER: user
      MYSQL_PASSWORD: password
      MYSQL_DATABASE: master
```

My Application.properties:

```
logging.level.com.example=DEBUG
logging.level.io.r2dbc=DEBUG

master.url = ${MASTER_URL}
```

And finally, my Java File:

```
@Configuration
//@ConfigurationProperties(prefix = "master")
@EnableR2dbcRepositories(entityOperationsRef = "masterEntityTemplate")
public class MasterConfig {

    @Value("${master.url}")
    private String url;

    @Bean
    @Qualifier(value = "masterConnectionFactory")
    public ConnectionFactory masterConnectionFactory() {

        System.out.println(">>>>>>>>>>>" + url);

        return ConnectionFactories.get(url);
        //.get("r2dbc:mysql://user:password@localhost/master");
    }
```

Thats the final error I am taking:

> Caused by: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Could not resolve placeholder 'MASTER_URL' in value "${MASTER_URL}"

Someone know how to solve this problem?

Thanks a lot

Comment: Why are you doing _any_ of this? Spring automatically reads environment variables into the spring configuration.

Comment: Which is your springboot service in the docker-compose file?  I only see a tenant service which is using a postgres image and a mysql service which is a mysql container.

Comment: @BoristheSpider Even, when I use the 'docker-compose environmental variables' directly in the Spring Boot, I have no idea why, Spring boot keeps not reading those.. See the test I am doing, in my SpringBootApplication : System.getenv("MASTER_URL")... show null.

Comment: @Carlos I do not have any service for SpringBoot in my docker-compose for now, I only have master-db(mysql), and tenant1-db(postgres)

Comment: Then that would explain why you are not getting the value set in compose.  Environment variables set in compose are injected into the container not set on the host.

Comment: @Carlos Make totally sense, I am gonna insert my Spring Boot App as a service. I will let you guys know , if solves my problem.

Answer (score -1):

The sythaxis for passing environment variables with in a compose file is varibaleName=value replace the colon(:) with the equals sign(=)

replace that:

MASTER_URL: r2dbc:mysql://user:password@localhost/master

with this:

- MASTER_URL=r2dbc:mysql://user:password@localhost/master

Comment: Both syntaxes should work equally well. OP's problem was likely because the Spring Boot application couldn't access environment variables defined in the Postgres or MySQL containers, as stated in the comments.